# How quickly transfer data from Android to PC(Delphi XE5, DataSnap)?

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe5

I want to transfer data from Android how fast the PC (Android device and PC that run the server Datasnap are in the same LAN). 
I use Delphi XE5, Datasnap. Datasnap with FireDac server connected to MSSQL. Here we exposed a table. In Android use SQLite in a table similara.La connection transfer from several thousand records up to tens of thousands of records. transfer takes too much about a minute to a thousand records. Now I realize the transfer from the device to the PC as follows:

```
 SQLConnection1.Connected:=True;
 ClientDataSet1.Active:=True;
 liteTabel1.Active:=True;
 while (not liteTabel1.eof) do
 begin
   ClientDataSet1.Insert;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f1').AsInteger:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f1').AsInteger;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f2').AsVariant:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f2').AsVariant;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f3').AsInteger:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f3').AsInteger;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f4').AsVariant:liteTabel1.FieldByName('f4').AsVariant;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f5').AsInteger:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f5').AsInteger;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f6').AsString:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f6').AsString;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f7').AsString:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f7').AsString;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f8').AsString:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f8').AsString;
   ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('f9').AsDateTime:=liteTabel1.FieldByName('f9').AsAsDateTime; 
   ClientDataSet1.Post;
   liteTabel1.Next;
 end;
  ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
  ClientDataSet1.Active:=False;
  SQLConnection1.Connected:=False;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `DatSetProvider` to copy data from your liteTable to your `ClientDataSet`? In my experience, copying data using a `DataSetProvider` is way too faster than copying fields one by one.

Comment: Copying record by record and field by field is slow. And you call FieldByName 19 times for each record. Ouch.